# How to flatten a tensorflow dataset along feature columns when using data.make_csv_dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using `tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset` to read CSV files having differing numbers of feature columns.

After reading each file I want to concatenate all the feature columns.

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(file_names[0],48,select_columns=['Load_residential_multi_0','Load_residential_multi_1'],shuffle=False)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
get_batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_batch = get_batch.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
      power_data = sess.run(get_batch)
print(power_data.keys())
```

Above code will give an ordered dictionary with two keys as shown below:

> odict_keys(['Load_residential_multi_0', 'Load_residential_multi_1'])

I can access individual features using the feature names. For example     `power_data['Load_residential_multi_0']`  will give me,

> ```
> array([[0.075 , 0.1225, 0.0775, 0.12  ],
>        [0.0875, 0.1125, 0.095 , 0.1025]], dtype=float32)
> ```

However, I want both the feature columns `'Load_residential_multi_0','Load_residential_multi_1'`to be concatenated.

I this I can do this using `dataset.flatmap(map_func)` but I am not sure what I should use as the argument to `flatmap()`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `dataset.map` you can concat both the dictionary values:

```
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.stack(list(x.values())))
get_batch = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting the following error when I use get_batch in session.                                                                                                              
Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops.Iterator object at 0x00000218E280B470> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.iterator_ops.Iterator'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a Iterator into a Tensor or Operation.)

Comment: You mean when you use the batch_size declared in `tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset` (48)?

Comment: Yes,batch_size  is 48.

Comment: Can you share a sample csv which produces the problem. In my example setup it works.

Comment: Sure, please find link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MsntHEVxOcXekbAxN6Co-pyRFqqn_5a_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the code I am using:                                                                    
`dataset= tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(file_name,48,select_columns=['Load_residential_multi_0','Load_residential_multi_1'],shuffle=False)
                                                                                                                    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.stack(list(x.values())))
get_batch= dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()                                                    
model.fit(get_batch,steps_per_epoch=2,batch_size=2,epochs=2,shuffle =True,verbose=1)`